# How to move elements of horizontal flatlist to left side of screen?

Tags: css, react-native

I have a horizontal flatlist:

```
<Container>
  {
    isLoading ?
    <Text style = {{ color: '#FFFFFF'}}> loading </Text>
    :
    <FlatList
      data={tokenHistory}
      renderItem={({item, index}) => renderItem({ item, index })}
      horizontal={true}
      inverted={true}
      ListFooterComponent={<FooterComponent />}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    />
  }
</Container>
```

it looks and works as intended, the only problem arises when there are 1 or 2 elements to render. When there are only 1 or 2 elements, the flatlist displays them on the right side of the screen. How can I get the elements to display to the left side of the screen?

Examples:

**When there is only one element, flatlist shows it on the right side of the screen**
[image]
**When there are only 2 elements, flatlist shows them on the right side of the screen**
[image: 2 elements aligning to the right side of the device]

My renderItem code:

```
return (
  <OuterColumn>
    <GradientRow> 
      <Gradient color={color} />
      { isFirst ? <EmptyView /> : <LineView color={color} /> }
    </GradientRow>
    
    <InnerColumn>
      <DateRow>
        <Text
          align="left"
          color={color}
          size="smedium"
          weight="heavy"
        >
        {date}     
        </Text>
      </DateRow>
      
      <Row>
        <Text
          align="left"
          color={color}
          size="smedium"
          weight="heavy"
        >
          {symbol}
        </Text>
        <Text
          align="right"
          color={colors.whiteLabel}
          size="smedium"
          weight="heavy"
        >
          {' '}{phrase}{suffix}
        </Text>
      </Row>
    </InnerColumn>
  </OuterColumn>
)
```

Is there a way to have the elements aligned to the left side of the screen?

Comment: can you add your renderItem code?

Comment: In your renderItem you can `justifyContent : 'flex-start'` to your element.

Comment: @DhavalSarvaiya added renderItem code

Comment: remove  `inverted={true}` from your `<Flatlist />` code